# Start activity without click on push notification's item

Tags: android

Here snippet:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainFragmentActivity_.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent,
                                 PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

And in `MainFragmentActivity`

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
boolean isSyncAction = intent.getBooleanExtra(NotificationsSyncModule.SYNC_ACTION, false);
}
```

So when I click on push notification's item the activity `MainFragmentActivity` is start.
Nice.

But now I want **WITHOUT**  click on push notification automate start activity when arrive push notification.
How I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you should be able to do

```
context.startActivity(...)
```

using your Service/IntentService(whatever is handling your push notifications).

Hope this helps!

Please also note that an app randomly 'jumping out' on push notifications might cause not-so-great UX - of course it all depends on your usecase. I also believe that from Android Q onward this will not be possible.

Comment: So would I, but remember - there are e.g. communicator/voip apps like Skype/Messenger, which might use push notifications and show full-screen call screen on notification received. I've also seen this behavior in bank apps.

Answer (score 1):

you just start your activity just after you have built your notification

```
Intent Intent = new Intent(context, MainFragmentActivity_.class);
Activity activity = (Activity) context;
activity.startActivity(intent)
```